# Is it possible to pass multiple names to logging.getLogger()?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

We wrote a python script that involves AWS (getting file from s3 bucket, transfer the processed file to remote machine using fabric / paramiko). When I turn the logging at DEBUG level, many logs are getting printed on the console. I just wanted my python file to be at DEBUG level and external modules like AWS, Paramiko should be at INFO file. Below is the code I used for that.

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('boto').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('paramiko').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('invoke').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('urllib3').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('fabric').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('s3transfer').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

It is working fine.

1. But is there any way to pass multiple names to getLogger some thing
   like

   ```
   logging.getLogger('boto|boto3').setLevel(logging.INFO)
   ```
2. Also for all Amazon services, can we set log level to INFO for all the services in one line instead
   of setting Log Levels to boto, boto3, botocore individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but this is a clear-cut use case for a loop.

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
for name in ['boto', 'boto3', ...]:
    logging.getLogger(name).setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Note that you may not want to set the *root* logger to debug, but a logger specific to your module/file.

```
logging.getLogger('myscript').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

---

It might be nice if all the AWS modules used loggers in a single `aws` namespace, in which case you could use

```
logging.getLogger('aws').setLevel(...)
```

and this would be inherited by `'aws.boto'`, `'aws.boto3'`, etc. But, that does not seem to be the case. Each module (`boto3`, certainly) defines a logger that inherits directly from the root logger.

(That said, you *could* treat the root logger as a proxy for whichever subset you want to configure, overriding root-level configurations in the others, and taking care to only use the root logger if you are happy with its configuration. But, this is probably fragile, and it's best to configure each logger as intended. Note that it might be easier to write a logging configuration file than to configure your loggers directly in your code.)